# How can I filter the list given to the function in the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have a data frame and you should write a function. How can I filter the list given to the function in the data frame ? How can I write the function ? I used pandas filter like this :

```
df.filter(items=['one', 'three'])
```

How can I don't use pandas?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you want to do?

Comment: I want to write a function like value_list (df, column, list). The output of this function must be in data frame format. The "value list" given to the function should filter in the corresponding column of the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something along these lines:

```
def value_list(df, col, list_):
    return df['col'][df['col'].isin(list_)]
```

Consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,4,2,3,4,1],'b':[1,2,2,1,1,2]})

def value_list(df, col, list_):
    return df[col][df[col].isin(list_)]

value_list(df,'a',[1,2,3])
```

If you want a portion of the dataframe instead of a column then use `df` instead of `df['col']` in the answer above.